# How to place GitLab behind nginx

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I just got a Raspberry Pi 4B and i would like to place on it Nextcloud and Gitlab servers.

Using the [instructions](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#raspberry-pi-os) i was able to install GitLab successfully on my RPI4.

As second step I diceded to install Nginx, since i would like to run more then one server on RPI4.

I followed the [instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html) and added [gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/-/blob/master/web-server/nginx/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf) to my

```
/etc/nginx/modules-enabled/
```

as I tried to restart my nginx i got using `sudo nginx -t` an error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf:19
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I belived that the problem is not there, since if i commit this line, i get

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf:23
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the sample from /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/gitlab-omnibus-nginx.conf is not a valid nginx config file, but just a snippet instead. The `upstream` and the `server` blocks need to be nested within the `http` block of your nginx config file.

Comment: I found the problem. You were right, it had something with http. The include of the *.conf was twiced, One with http block and one without.